ISC-kea dhcp reservations do not appear to be working with my configuration
I cut over my network to use isc-kea v2.2.0 but it doesn't appear that the reservations are being honored. I created a testing host and instead of getting its reservation IP it's getting a dynamic IP from the pool range of the subnet. I ran my isc-dhcpd configuration through the migration tool and then had to modify some settings as high availability and other fields have changed so much.
My Kea configuration files are these. I'm wondering what field I might be missing, or did I misconfigure a setting for reservations to work?
#// kea-dhcp4.conf
{
  "Dhcp4": {
    #// 1d lease time global
    "valid-lifetime": 86400,
    #// T1 hard set value
    #//"renew-timer": 900,
    #// T2 hard set value
    #//"rebind-timer": 1800,
    "calculate-tee-times": true,
    #// T1 default is 50% the lease period
    "t1-percent": 0.5,
    #// T2 default is 87.5% the lease period
    "t2-percent": 0.875,
    "interfaces-config": {
      "interfaces": [ "eth0" ]
    },
    "reservation-mode": "global",
    "host-reservation-identifiers": [
      "hw-address"
    ],
    "lease-database": {
      "type": "memfile",
      "lfc-interval": 3600,
      "persist": true,
      #// Default "[kea-install-dir]/var/lib/kea/kea-leases4.csv"
      #//"name": "/var/log/kea/kea-leases4.csv",
      "max-row-errors": 100
    },
    "control-socket": {
      "socket-type": "unix",
      "socket-name": "/run/kea/kea4-ctrl-socket"
    },
    "expired-leases-processing": {
      #// 1h, check leases that expired every hour
      "reclaim-timer-wait-time": 3600,
      #// 2d, for the device to come back and use the same IP
      "hold-reclaimed-time": 172800,
      #// Default 100, Process all reclaimed leases at one time
      "max-reclaim-leases": 0,
      #// Default 250ms, how long it can process the reclaim
      "max-reclaim-time": 0
    },
    "option-data": [ {
        #// Default DNS servers for all
        "name": "domain-name-servers",
        "code": 6,
        "data": "9.9.9.9, 1.1.1.1"
        #//"data": "192.168.1.6, 192.168.1.7"
    } ],
    #// https://kb.isc.org/docs/kea-hook-libraries
    "hooks-libraries": [
      {
        "library": "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/kea/hooks/libdhcp_lease_cmds.so"
      },
      {
        "library": "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/kea/hooks/libdhcp_ha.so",
        "parameters": {
          "high-availability": [ {
            "this-server-name": "dhcp-001",
            "mode": "hot-standby",
            "heartbeat-delay": 10000,
            "max-response-delay": 60000,
            "max-ack-delay": 5000,
            "max-unacked-clients": 5,
            "sync-timeout": 60000,
            "peers": [
              {
                "name": "dhcp-001",
                "url": "http://192.168.1.6:8000/",
                "role": "primary"
              },
              {
                "name": "dhcp-002",
                "url": "http://192.168.1.7:8000/",
                "role": "standby"
              }
            ]
          } ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "loggers": [ {
      "name": "kea-dhcp4",
      "output_options": [
        {
          "output": "stdout",
          "pattern": "%-5p %m\n"
        },
        {
          "output": "/var/log/kea/kea-dhcp4.log",
          "maxsize": 2048000,
          "maxver": 4
        }
      ],
      "severity": "INFO",
      "debuglevel": 0
    } ],
    "subnet4": [
      <?include "/etc/kea/subnet-1-trust.conf"?>
     ],
    "option-def": [ #// Used for the management network unifi APs
      {
        "space": "ubnt",
        "name": "unifi-address",
        "code": 1,
        "type": "ipv4-address"
    } ],
    "client-classes": [ {
      "name": "ubnt",
      #// from: match if (substring(option dhcp.vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4)) = 'ubnt'
      "test": "substring(option[60].hex,0,4) == 'ubnt'",
      "option-data": [
        {
          "space": "dhcp4",
          "name": "vendor-class-identifier",
          "code": 60,
          "data": "ubnt"
        },
        {
          "name": "vendor-encapsulated-options",
          "code": 43
        },
        {
          "space": "ubnt",
          "name": "unifi-address",
          "code": 1,
          "data": "192.168.1.23"
        }
      ],
      "option-def": [ {
          "name": "vendor-encapsulated-options",
          "code": 43,
          "type": "empty",
          "encapsulate": "ubnt"
        } ]
    } ]
  }
}

#//subnet-1-trust.conf
{
  #// Trust Network
  "id": 1,
  "subnet": "192.168.1.0/24",
  "option-data": [
    {
      "name": "subnet-mask",
      "code": 1,
      "data": "255.255.255.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "routers",
      "code": 3,
      "data": "192.168.1.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "domain-name-servers",
      "code": 6,
      "data": "9.9.9.9, 1.1.1.1"
    }
  ],
  #// 24h 1day before having to renew
  #//"valid-lifetime": 86400,
  "valid-lifetime": 3600,
  #// 3d
  "max-valid-lifetime": 259200,
  "pools": [ {
    "pool": "192.168.1.128 - 192.168.1.254"
  } ],
  "reservations": [ {
    "hostname": "docker-host-001",
    "hw-address": "06:40:1d:7a:f4:b1",
    "ip-address": "192.168.1.11"
  } ]
}

To test and "clear" any possible caching, I've been removing the lease with the restapi. I stopped the kea-dhcp4 service, deleted all lines in the CSV leases file referencing the testing host, and started the service back up.
http --json POST http://127.0.0.1:8000 \
  service:='["dhcp4"]' \
  command=lease4-del \
  arguments:='{"ip-address": "192.168.1.211"}'

sudo systemctl stop kea-dhcp4-server.service 
sudo sed -i '/docker-host/d' /var/lib/kea/kea-leases4.csv
sudo systemctl start kea-dhcp4-server.service 
sudo tail -f /var/log/kea/kea-dhcp4.log

Then delete the IP from the host and restart its network service or even reboot the host completely.

I figured out what I was missing. Either the migration tool put an old line in the config when converting my isc-dhcp config files or I must have read an old version of the documentation at some point.
I had "reservation-mode": "global", in the main dhcp4 config file. Since v1.9.1 it was split in to 3 options of true/false. Replacing it with the following has made the reservations work. My settings are very specific where reservations will not be inside the dynamic pool range so I can save the server some work by not having to verify leases.
    "reservations-global": false,
    "reservations-in-subnet": true,
    "reservations-out-of-pool": true,

See https://kea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arm/dhcp4-srv.html#fine-tuning-dhcpv4-host-reservation for the different options and reasoning for each setup.
